# How to import amharic data from to mysql database?

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf8mb4

I found this from stack overflow

```
ALTER DATABASE ethioVision CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

but still cannot add file

Comment: What happens instead? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: i restarted sql service after this but still the same, i was trying to import amharic(Ethiopian language) data.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the default character sets of a table or a schema does not change the data in the column itself, it only changes the default to apply the next time you add a table or add a column to a table.

To convert current data, alter one table at a time:

```
ALTER TABLE <name> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```